# In the SharpSVN API, what does the SvnSslServerTrustEventArgs Save Member exactly do?

Tags: c#, api, member, sharpsvn

I saw that this was used in sample code to accept all the warnings (like certificate warnings) when trying to connect to a repository but I wasn't sure exactly what the Save=true; was specifically doing whether it was saving the fact that these certificates were accepted ect. Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stores the settings in %appdata%\Subversion\auth. If you don't set the save value the result only applies to the current session/SvnClient instance.